# SQL Database Select, Sort, and Eliminate Duplicates without DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

In a sample SQL database, I've got Invoice Totals and Vendor Names on two separate tables.

As a general orientation, here is the current code I've created:

```
SELECT TOP 5 InvoiceTotal, VendorName
FROM Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal DESC;
```

I'm looking for the top 5 Invoice Totals displayed WITHOUT repeating any of the Vendor Names. For example, my current output is:

```
137966.19   Malloy Lithographing Inc
26881.40    Malloy Lithographing Inc
23517.58    Malloy Lithographing Inc
21842.00    Data Reproductions Corp
20551.18    Malloy Lithographing Inc
```

However, the target output is something like:

```
137966.19   Malloy Lithographing Inc
21842.00    Data Reproductions Corp
20076.01    Smith & Co
14590.00    Tim's Management LTD
13878.50    HelloWorld Corp
```

Is this something I can make happen in Management Studio? I've tried implementing DISTINCT, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
SELECT TOP 5 MAX(InvoiceTotal) AS Total, VendorName
FROM Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
GROUP BY VendorName
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: It wont let me accept your answer yet, but it does work. Thanks.  However, I get the Max() part, but I don't understand what the ORDER BY 1 is doing. Why 1?

Comment: 1 just means to order by the first column; you can use an index like that, or the name of the column you want to order by.

Comment: in this case 1 is the ordinal position of the first column.  so whatever column is the first column it will order by that.